# Install app on connected device via cmd/terminal or by code

Tags: android, cmd, installation, auto-update

I have one apk file which is stored internally on my samsung phone. I want to install that apk using `cmd`. I mean is there any command or any code available for that??? So, I can install that app via usb or is there any code to install app or is there any soure code to update my app. 
*Any help would be appreciated.*

I tried following command which couldn't worked for me...

> adb install example.apk
>
> adb install -s example.apk

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: have you tried adb install -r example.apk

Comment: I got it by myself... I want to share  link http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-update-android-apk-outside-the-playstore/

Answer (score 0):

Before you can run your app on a device, you must enable USB debugging on your device. You can find the option under Settings > Developer options.

Once your device is set up and connected via USB, you can install your app using  the adb tool:

```
adb -d install path/to/your_app.apk
```

For More details refer 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Comment: thnx for replying raguMCA but this is not my solution. I looking for to install     app from code not with the help of usb and fortunately It has been founded by myself and here is the link [ http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-update-android-apk-outside-the-playstore/ ]